# How to center align 3+ divs dynamically in rows of 3?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to center dynamically generated divs (containing other divs and dynamic content), and have them align horizontally with up to 3 in a row, currently they're in line, but are not centered in parent div(ie. there is leftover space to the right). I've used alot of methods on other posts to no avail. Any help would be fantastic! :)

HTML: (PHP will generate any number of these)

```
<div id="div$j" class="divs">
    <div class="image_ratio">
        <img src="photos/Asset 1-100.jpg" onerror="this.src='Social_Icons/Rectangle 157@2x.png'">
    </div>
    <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
    <form type="text" name="form$j" id="form$j" action="AJAX.php" method="post">
        <div class="aligner">
            <button type="button" class="button_div")">X</button>
            <button type="button" class="button_div">Y</button>
            <button type="button" class="button_div">Z</button>
        </div><br>
        <input type="hidden"/>
        <input type="hidden"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

and all of these divs are wrapped together in:

```
<div class="BAJAX">.....</div>
```

CSS:

```
.BAJAX {
    grid-area: pieces;
    border: solid;
}


.image_ratio {
        position: relative;
        width: 25vmin;
        height: 35vmin;

    }

    .image_ratio img {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;

    }

    .divs {
        width: 25vmin;
        z-index: 98;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 2.5%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: solid;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use **flexbox**. Your container (parent) will have `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` (so items can fill the space evenly). Then on each individual item (child) you will be setting `flex-basis: 33%` (or less as you will want items to have some `margin`/`padding` to delimit one from the other).

More info on this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Demo: https://codepen.io/Manu92/pen/PvvdMp

Comment: Would the child divs need to be display: flex; aswell?

Comment: The immediate childdren won't need. Depending on how much nesting you do then yes, you may need to re-introduce ```display: flex``` at some point.

Comment: Okay nice, it aligns them however, how would i get only 3 divs/row?

Comment: Check this example out: https://codepen.io/Manu92/pen/PvvdMp - it's by using ```flex-basis``` on the children

Comment: Sorry, my bad, check the above again, I've amended it. You also need to add ```flex-wrap: wrap``` on the parent.

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou, also using a flex-basis of 32% made it perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div class="aligner">` use `<div class="row">.`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css

Also you can add it inside tag `<h3>`.